# Calculate the mean and variance of 1000 randomly generated numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: python

I am new to python. Anyone have an answer to my problem? I have already made the list 1000 random numbers between 0 and 1. Now I would like to do the mean and their variance.

```
for i in range(1000):
    print(A=random.random())
```

Comment: What research did you do? I effortlessly can find dozens of resources to compute statistical measures in Python.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to create the array, not just print it.
You can do this through numpy.

```
import numpy as np
```

Create random array of 1000 numbers between 0 and 1

```
a = np.random.rand(1000)

print(a.mean())
print(a.var())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `statistics` module, it has  `variance` function.

Also, your code will not generate a list. Use either a list comprehension or a loop appending to a list to generate your list of numbers.

```
# Importing Statistics module 
import statistics 
import random as r
  
# Creating a sample of data 
sample = []
for _ in range(1000):
    sample.append(r.random())

#Alternate method using list comprehension
sample = [r.random() for _ in range(1000)] 
  
# Prints variance of the sample set 
  
# Function will automatically calculate 
# it's mean and set it as xbar 
print("Variance of sample set is {statistics.variance(sample)})"
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-variance/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually append them to a list, since printing them is **not** making a list out of them:

```py
import random

myList = []
for i in range(1000):
    myList.append(random.random())
```

Then, you can just use the `mean` and `variance` functions inside the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module:

```py
import random
import statistics

myList = []
for i in range(1000):
    myList.append(random.random())

print("The mean is", statistics.mean(myList))
print("The variance is", statistics.variance(myList))
```